# Sending data from javascript to php using XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I want to send `myVariable=45` from javascript and show it on screen by using php `echo myVariable`. All is happening in the same page called index.php. How can I accomplish this? This is my try:

javascript (The idea is to mimic the POST method when using forms):

```js
let data = new FormData();
data.append('myVariable', 45);

let myRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
myRequest.open('POST', 'index.php', true);
myRequest.send(data);
```

Then on my php code:

```php
echo $_POST['myVariable'];
```

Loading the page it says:

`php Warning: Undefined array key "myVariable"`

But when I print the response on loading the page I can see the value is there by adding this to my javascript code:

```js
myRequest.onload = function () {
    console.log(this.response);
};
```

**Edit:** This is all I have in my `index.php`:

```php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="./js/request.js">
  </script>
  <title>Document</title>

</head>

<body>
  <?php

echo $_POST["myVariable"];

?>
</body>


</html>
```

The rest is in my  `request.js` file:

```js
let data = new FormData();
data.append('myVariable', 45);

let myRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
myRequest.open('POST', 'index.php', true);
myRequest.send(data);
myRequest.onload = function () {
    console.log(this.response);
};
```

Comment: _Loading the page it says:_ What does that mean exactly. Do you mean if you run `localhost/index.php` on the browser?

Comment: yes, when accessing the `index.php` page.

Comment: But it works without the error when you use the javascript code, right?

Comment: yes, it seems that way because the response back shows the value printed out.

Comment: Please show the complete contents of `index.php`

Comment: @RiggsFolly Just added the full code

Comment: I would suggest you seperate the PHP that response to the AJAX call from the PHP that builds the page. Treat the AJAX functions like a liitle subroutime library

Comment: I guess it warn to you when open the page, because of your request doesnt triggered, php works first after your script. Anyway if you doesnt want to warning just add if statement worh isset.